Angle between a tangent line and another line
I was solving exercises from Do Carmo’s and one exercise goes: Show that the tangent lines to the regular paramterized curve $\alpha(t)=(3t,2t^2,2t^3)$ make a constant angle with the line $y=0$, $z=x$. 
What I think should work (but doesn’t) is take $\alpha’(t)=(3,4t,6t^2)$ and $(1,0,1)$ generating the second line and find the angle between them:
$\frac{\alpha’(t).(1,0,1)}{||\alpha’(t)||\sqrt{2}}$, which doesn’t appear to be constant. I feel like I am missing something fundamental here so any help is appreciated.

There is a typo in the book. It's not $2t^2$, it's $3t^2$.

Your approach is almost correct.
Let $\alpha(t) = (3t, 3t^{2}, 2t^{3})$ and $u = (1, 0, 1)$.
We have that $\alpha'(t) = (3, 6t, 6t^{2}) = 3(1, 2t, 2t^{2})$.
Note that, on the one hand using the definition of the dot product:
$$
\begin{align}
\alpha'(t) \cdot u &= 3 \cdot 1 + 6t \cdot 0 + 6t^{2} \cdot 1 = 3 + 6t^{2} \\
 &= 3(1 + 2t^{2}) \tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
An on the other, using that $a \cdot b = |a||b|\cos \theta$ (with $\theta$ being the angle between $a$ and $b$):
$$
\begin{align}
\alpha'(t) \cdot u &= \sqrt{3^{2} + (6t)^2 + (6t^{2})^{2}} \sqrt{2} \cos \theta \\
 &= 3\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1 + 4t^{2} + 4t^{4}} \cos \theta \\
 &= 3\sqrt{2}\sqrt{(1 + 2t^2)^2} \cos \theta \\
 &= 3\sqrt{2}(1 + 2t^2) \cos \theta \tag 2
\end{align}
$$
Therefore by $(1)$ and $(2)$ we have that:
$$
\begin{align}
 3(1 + 2t^2) = 3\sqrt{2}(1 + 2t^2)\cos \theta &\iff \cos \theta = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \\
 &\iff \theta = \frac{\pi}{4}
\end{align}
$$

How is $(2t^2)'=6t$? I think you are meaning $3t^2$.

Yeah, I made a typo. Ty for noticing.

Thanks for the detailed answer!

No worries! Don't forget to mark the question as answered to help (possible) future visitors. @GoGoMath
